# how to install Roboform in Firefox

Tags: firefox

I want to use Roboform to remember my passwords but I don't know how to install Roboform in Firefox.I have asked some friends, they don't know, neither. Anybody know please tell me.Thanks a lot！！

Answer (score 1):

http://www.roboform.com/platforms/linux/firefox

1. Download file.
2. Rightclick file, and choose "Open With -> Firefox"